# Passing an object as a parameter in Java

Tags: java

There is a scenario

Say I have a class `People` & a utility class `PeopleUtil` with a method `computeTotalNumberOfPeople`

In a separate class say `EvaluatePeople` where I have code

```
People people = new People();
people.setValue(10);
people.setX(45);
PeopleUtil.computeTotalNumberOfPeople(people);
this.persistPeople(people);
```

In the `computeTotalNumberOfPeople` method

```
public void computeTotalNumberOfPeople(People people){
  //logic for computing total no of people & then
  int totalPeople = certainIntValue; 
  // I can return the totalPeople value from this method but I am not doing it just for the sake of this scenario
  people.setTotalNumberOfPeople(totalPeople);
}
```

When I look at the People object in the db row I see the `totalNumberOfPeople` value persisted. Which is actually fine.

My question is, I am a little confused about it, shouldn't `computeTotalNumberOfPeople` method return the people object, which has an extra set value, to the method caller code & then that object should be passed to the peristPeople method as an argument?

I hope you understand what I mean, it doesn't seem right someway

Comment: You are only passing object references to the method calls. So you are operating on the same object in every method. So returning back the object is unnecessary.

Comment: You *can* modify the method to return the `people` object it was given, which may indeed subjectively make the code more easily understandable in this case (depending on personal opinion).  It's not technically necessary because the object is passed by reference, and so any modifications made to the object referenced by that variable will be reflected in any other variable which references that same instance of the object.

Comment: As a general comment, I consider setters a bad practice. You want your classes to be as immutable as possible, otherwise tracking their state can be tricky

Comment: Codebender and David are correct. You should probably spend some time reading about the differences between pass by value and pass by reference. Here is a good [article on this topic](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) which explains how Java implements the passing of data to methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are mutable – they can be changed.

So when you call `people.setTotalNumberOfPeople(totalPeople)`, you are setting the `totalNumberOfPeople` variable (or whatever it's called inside the `People` class) to `totalPeople` for the `people` object.

When you exit the `computeTotalNumberOfPeople` method, the object is still the same one that was modified – the changes from the method persist.

One way to think about it is passing a reference to `people`. When you call `computeTotalNumberOfPeople(people)`, you are passing a *reference* to `people`. When `people` is modified, you modifying the same location in memory, and so the changes persist.

Comment: Side-effects methods are not particularly idiomatic in Java though. I would simply return the total number of people and let the caller decide what to do with it. It's more flexible, more idiomatic and is a cleaner separation of concerns